# Flexbox from SCSS working correctly on Firefox but not on other browsers (e.g. Chrome, Edge, ...)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I am currently working on a project using Gatsby.js combined with SASS for styling. Creating an input field we have encountered the issue that the container and its items only display correctly on Firefox, but not on other browsers such as Chrome, Edge, IE etc. Interestingly it displays correctly on mobile view for any browser.

I have tried a few things and when removing `display: flex;` from the pages SCSS file it displayed the same way on all browsers used (but of course, looked bad). All pages get styling from a main/global file, but have their individual SCSS files too.

The input field taken from its component:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={styles.formBox}>
            <fieldset className={styles.formGroup}>
                <label htmlFor="production">Text</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    name="production"
                    value={this.state.production}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    className={styles.numberInput}
                    placeholder="Enter input"
                />
                <label htmlFor="unit">Text</label>
                <select
                    name="unit"
                    className={styles.selectionField}
                    value={this.state.unit}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                >
                    <option value="Value1" className={styles.optionField}>Value1</option>
                    <option value="Value2" className={styles.optionField}>Value2</option>
                </select>
                <label htmlFor="unit">Text</label>
                <select
                    name="weight"
                    className={styles.selectionField}
                    value={this.state.weight}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                >
                    <option value="value1" className={styles.optionField}>value1</option>
                    <option value="value2" className={styles.optionField}>value2</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" className="btn text-uppercase btn-primary--orange hover-effect btn-block-xs-only">Text</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The SCSS file:

```
$border-radius: .25rem;
$button-border-radius: 290486px;
$input-border-width: 2px;
$dark-blue: #000460;
$font-color: #07112a;

.form-box {
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    box-shadow: 0 22px 45px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 24px;
}

.form-group {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    // display: -webkit-flex;
    // display: -ms-flex;
    // display: -webkit-box;
    // display: flex;

    label {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .number-input {
        border: $input-border-width solid $dark-blue;
        border-radius: $border-radius;
        color: $font-color;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 1em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        // width: 100%;

        &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            /* Edge */
            color: $font-color;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        &:-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: $font-color;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        &::placeholder {
            color: $font-color;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }


    .selection-field {
        background-color: $dark-blue;
        background-image:
            linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, $dark-blue 50%),
            linear-gradient(135deg, $dark-blue 50%, transparent 50%),
            radial-gradient(white 70%, transparent 72%);
        background-position:
            calc(100% - 20px) calc(1.25em + 2px),
            calc(100% - 15px) calc(1.25em + 2px),
            calc(100% - .5em) .75em;
        background-size:
            5px 5px,
            5px 5px,
            1.5em 1.5em;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: $input-border-width solid $dark-blue;
        border-radius: $border-radius;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 1em;
        min-width: 100px;
        padding-left: .5em;

        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;

        &::-ms-expand {
            display: none;
        }

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        &:focus {
            background-image:
                linear-gradient(45deg, $dark-blue 50%, transparent 50%),
                linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, $dark-blue 50%),
                radial-gradient(white 70%, transparent 72%);
            background-position:
                calc(100% - 15px) 1.25em,
                calc(100% - 20px) 1.25em,
                calc(100% - .5em) .75em;
            background-size:
                5px 5px,
                5px 5px,
                1.5em 1.5em;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            color: white;
            outline: 0;
        }

        .option-field {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: $font-color;
        }
    }

    input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    input[type=number] {
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }

    button {
        border-radius: $button-border-radius;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .form-group {
        flex-direction: column;

        .number-input,
        .selection-field {
            height: 55px;
            margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Firefox (how it is supposed to look:

[image: Firefox (how it is supposed to look)]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

I can't quite wrap my head around why this is happening. What can I try next?

Comment: It looks to me like you are at more than 100% zoom in the Chrome screenshot.

Comment: Nope, both screenshots were taken fullscreen at 100% zoom.

Comment: This is what the code you posted produces: https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/eYZmreY

Comment: I'm sorry, due to my work I am only able to post snippets from my code.

Comment: Could you at least post HTML and CSS so it can be run?

Comment: Once again I'm sorry, but this is going to be difficult as this is a child component of another page I cannot post. I am very sorry for the inconvenience. The snippets are the only thing I feel comfortable sharing and are most likely the reason for the issue.

Comment: Post an HTML/CSS version of the most minimal snippet you can. You don't have to post the whole page - but if you can certainly create a minimal version of what you are doing. Without that, we cannot help you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You could easily convert the code you have posted to HTML and CSS.

Comment: I will do this as soon as possible in coordination with a coworker who knows what I can and can't post. I'm quite new to this, so my apologies. I am very grateful that you're trying to help me.

Comment: You have already posted it?

Comment: @Turnip I have already censored the code snippets. I know it is frustrating as you're kindly trying to help me, but I'm not in the position to share the complete code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely related to this.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .form-group {
        flex-direction: column;

        .number-input,
        .selection-field {
           height: 55px;
```

Your Chrome viewport may be smaller causing them to stack as columns, and would also explain the cropped height of the inputs

Comment: Sorry to ask, how does this affect a the fullscreen view on a desktop? Because it properly displays on any mobile browser.

Comment: It is still possible that, even though you're on a desktop, your viewport is smaller than you think, causing the problem. Remember viewport is not necessarily your screen size.

Comment: So there is a difference between the viewport in Firefox and the other browsers (Chrome, Edge, ...)?

Comment: It is possible. Did you check your viewport size on each browser?

Comment: I checked the viewport sizes for the different browsers and it is the same for each (1920x969). Could it be that the flexbox is working differently/better for Firefox than for other browsers? Because as stated earlier, if I switch to the mobile view it works correctly on all browsers.

(if I remove the _display: inline-flex_ from the form group it looks the same on Firefox as on the other browsers. So it seems the display only works on Firefox).